# After Windows XP profile migration internet explorer could not open HTTPS sites

Tags: windows-xp, https, internet-explorer

After Windows XP profile migration internet explorer (6,7,8) could not open HTTPS sites. It is working for local administrator account, but not working for limited domain user account. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.
The solution is to log on as local administrator, load the NTUSER.DAT file into registry, then check for Full control rights and put the mark on Replace permission entries on all child objects. Unload hive, log in as user. Everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Could  you clear all cockies  ,history and etc . After that try again.

Answer (score 0):

Brillant! In my case I'm in a AD Domain configuration and no need for the user to logoff.

Solution is:

Go to the Domain Server or use any account with domain administrator rights, from there open Regedit. Click on File -> Connect Network Registry. And put in the remote PC name that has problem with https. Right-click on the SID, click on Permission, Click on Advance, put in the the user account, and click on "Replace all Child...."